# How to stop LaTeX from forcing single line paragraphs on two lines

Tags: spacing

I have a document containing some short paragraphs which would fit on a single line using normal spacing. When typesetting those paragraphs LaTex apparently tries hard to stretch those lines (the words) far enough to make it a two-line paragraph. That produces some very ugly paragraphs. LaTex even hyphenates the last word of the paragraph to get only the shortest possible part of it on the second line.

I tried adjusting the word stretching by lowering the setting for `\fontdimen3\font` to `0.2pt` but this does not feel right.

Is it possible to tell LaTeX not to stretch paragraphs on at least 2 lines?

### Edit:

I found the cause deep down in our templates:

```
\tolerance 1414
\emergencystretch 1.5em
```

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half*]{scrartcl}
\tolerance 1414
\emergencystretch 1.5em
\begin{document}
   This is a sentence that would usually fit on one line with normal spacing.
\end{document}
```

Removing one of both lines fixes the spacing of one line paragraphs. I am not yet familiar with what those commands do exactly, but I assume they had been added because some of the generated code produced overfull text lines.

Still, I don't understand why - with these settings - LaTeX tries to produce an extra line in the paragraph. From what I understand, `\tolerance` and `\emergencystretch` are supposed to jump in when formatting within the default rules is not possible. Where am I wrong?

### Edit2

The `parskip=half*` setting for the `srcartcl` document class appears to play a role in this game, also.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. (LaTeX certainly does not 'try to make paragraphs at least two lines'.)

Comment: If you have a lots of short paragraphs together, perhaps you could put them into one of the list environments?  Alternatively maybe setting `\raggedright` for some portion of your document.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. @Joseph: Good to know, LaTeX does not try to make paragraphs at least two lines, so maybe its something in my setup. I will try to provide a MWE but that's not so easy right now, because I'm within a system generating TeX code from a model. But I'll try to strip it down.

Comment: @Thruston: Thanks also for proposing the list environment, but I am dealing with LaTeX code generated from a model and the generator cannot decide wether a short paragraph should be part of a list. Sometimes it's just a sentence that is meant to stand alone. Also I cannot do any manual tweaking of paragraphs in the LaTeX code -- I have to find a general solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `parskip=half`  and *not* `half*`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, 
  parskip=half,% <=====
  bibliography=totoc, 
  final,  
  numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
```

Read the documentation of *[KOMA-Script](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)* for the difference.

Comment: Might be worth commenting that in the `.log` with setting `parskip=half*` you get a warning about an overfull box, which is why TeX is fiddling with the paragraph at all.

Comment: Thanks Herbert and Joseph for your fast response - that was the solution!